# Finding the $\log$ of a matrix by contour integration

Tags: matrices, reference-request, logarithms

My teacher presented this way of determining the logarithm of a matrix $\Omega$ in class today:

$$\log \Omega = \frac1{2\pi i}\oint_{\Gamma} (\zeta I - \Omega)^{-1} \log \zeta \,d\zeta.$$

Does anyone have a reference where I can read about this?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holomorphic_functional_calculus

Comment: See http://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/729/NA-07-17.pdf.